# This.props.history is undefined, if called from child component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-props

I am trying to validate the answers from inside the parent component. The validateAnswer function gets triggered and almost works as it should.

But I want to change the site if it was validated. So I call `this.props.history.push` from the parent. 
And this gives me an error because history is undefined.

```
<Answers handleClick={e => this.validateAnswer(e)} />

//Function to validate the Answer in the parent
    validateAnswer = (event) => {
    if (true) {
      //navigate to /email
      this.props.history.push({
        pathname: '/email',
        state: { lastPage: 'question' },
      });

    //Child component
         <Button
          name="1"
          label="Afrika"
          handleClick={props.handleClick}
        />
```

How could I fix this? Should I validate the answer directly in the Answer component?

Comment: What does logging `this` in your `validateAnswer()` function return?

Comment: Have you tried using withRouter HoC ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<Answers handleClick={this.validateAnswer} />

// Function to validate the Answer in the parent
validateAnswer(event){
if (true) {
  //navigate to /email
  this.props.history.push({
    pathname: '/email',
    state: { lastPage: 'question' },
  });

// Child component
 <Button
  name="1"
  label="Afrika"
  handleClick={(e) => props.handleClick(e) }
/>
```

Comment: I tried it like that, but still got the exact same error.